# What is the correct way to use dot punctuation to end this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, periods

Which of the following way of using `.` punctuation is correct? There are two sentences here.

> Donald Trump became the President of the U.S. The election took place in 2016.

> Donald Trump became the President of the U.S.. The election took place in 2016.

Comment: dot punctuation??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only one period. Using two is visually confusing as it resembles an ellipsis (...). Some style guides recommend not separating letters of an acronym/initialism with periods at all (so, US instead of U.S.) in some or all cases. But when including them, use only one when the acronym/initialism occurs at the end of a sentence.